# How to inherit a variable defined inside __init__ method of a class in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, tkinter

I want the `Pin` variable which takes some input in class `StartPage` to be inherited by the class `Options`, but using any code that uses `Pin` variable for eg. `print(Pin)` gives an error `NameError: name 'Pin' is not defined`. Passing both `StartPage` and `tk.Frame` as parent to class `Option` generates the error `TypeError Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Frame, StartPage`. Don't Judge me, as I am new to both Tkinter and OOP, any explained solution is highly appreciated.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter 4 digit pin", font=controller.title_font, fg="red")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        Pin = tk.Entry(self, bd = 4, relief="groove", show="*", font=20, justify='center')
        Pin.pack()

        submit = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=12,font=tkfont.Font(size=12),command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Options"), cursor="hand2")
        submit.pack()



class Options(tk.Frame,StartPage):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        print(Pin)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        f1=tk.Frame(self)
        f1.pack()
        f2=tk.Frame(self)
        f2.pack(side="bottom")
        button1 = tk.Button(f1, text="Balance Inquiry",relief="flat", padx=30, justify='left', cursor="hand2", fg="red", font=tkfont.Font(size=10),
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.pack(side="left")

        button2 = tk.Button(f1, text="Deposit",relief="flat", padx=50, justify='right', cursor="hand2", fg="red", font=tkfont.Font(size=10),
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button2.pack(side="left")

        button3 = tk.Button(f2, text="Withdraw",relief="flat", padx=50, justify='left', cursor="hand2", fg="red", font=tkfont.Font(size=10),
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageThree"))
        button3.pack(side="left")

        button4 = tk.Button(f2, text="Pin Change",relief="flat", padx=50, justify='right', cursor="hand2", fg="red", font=tkfont.Font(size=10),
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageFour"))
        button4.pack(side="left")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the Pin variable which takes some input in class StartPage to
>   be inherited by the class Options.

Use `self.Pin`. Also there is convention for instance names to start with lowercase, so `self.pin`.
Initialisation should also be with `self`:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.pin = tk.Entry(self, bd = 4, relief="groove", show="*", font=20, justify='center')
    self.pin.pack()
    ...
```

and always put your parent's constructor as first statement in child's `__init__`.

```
class Options(StartPage):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        StartPage.__init__(self, parent)
        print(self.pin)
```

**What should you do?**

[Composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance).
If you want to have just one field from `StartPage` in your `Options` class you can simply pass `pin` as argument.

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.pin = tk.Entry(self, bd = 4, relief="groove", show="*", font=20, justify='center')
        self.pin.pack()
        ...


class Options(fk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, pin):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        print(pin)
        ...
```

And then from outside it will look like this:

```
start_page = StartPage(some_parent, some_controller)
options = Options(some_parent, some_controller, start_page.pin)
```